# How to read xml file(toolsbox.xml) in React typescript

Tags: reactjs, xml, typescript, blockly

I am unable to import xml file in tsx file, but in jsx file i can able to access that xml file

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define a module for typescript to evaluate, otherwise it will try to look for something like `toolbox.xml.ts`.

Something along these lines in a file called XML.d.ts (for this placed in a folder @types in src):

```
declare module "*.xml" {
  const doc: any; // Change this to an actual XML type
  export default doc;
}
```

and add `"typeRoots": ["src/@types", "node_modules/@types"]` to your tsconfig.json (this makes typescript pick up the new typings file along with all installed types).

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue and am not sure how this works; I cannot even solve a simple txt file import issue. In my case, my target is esnext and ESM modules